# PHP Send multistring email

Tags: php, html

trying to use a EOD tag to send an email via PHP, heres my code:

The Code is too large, I pasted it on pastebin:
   http://pastebin.com/KK3QZx6p

Dreamweaver has an error on line two and the actual browser reports an error on the last line (the script tag that includes jQuery)

I have tried backslashes and all, but the EOD tags are being syntax highlighted, is that maybe the issue?

I basically want to send an email, and the main body I want to be a html email, I know you can use the concatenation, although if there is a way to paste it in using a multiline string and send it, that would be great, although the EOD tag, simply isn't highlighting, like I have done something wrong

Error From Browser: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/a8526867/public_html/index.php

Dreamweaver is erroring on the second line

Comment: Please provide the smallest possible sample of your code with all extraneous code separated out of it.

Comment: As @TecBrat said, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The link to your code can become invalid if the linked page changes. This would render your question useless.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I guess '{' at the last row gives a problem. You might try to escape it. But anyway, I don't think it's a good idea to use js or jquery in an email.

Comment: The line straight after the first line `$_message = EOD` is causing an error on dreamweaver. I cant see a { symbol.